# displaying a new textview with the result of a request to a sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I would like to have a button which creates a new textview at the click of it. I have the onCreate method which executes the following function:

```
public void request(View v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID,
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
    };


    String sortOrder =
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                    // don't filter by row groups
            sortOrder                                 // The sort order
    );


}
```

How do I show the content of the cursor on the new textview?
Which method do I need to use and how I complete the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get the string which you desire to display from the cursor object.

`String strColumnValue=cursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE)));`

COLUMN_NAME_TITLE is the column specified in the table

Now that you have got the string value. Create a textview dynamically use the code below `

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText(strColumnValue);
this.layout_name.addView(tv);
```

Here "layout_name" is the specific layout that you want to add the textview in.